# Need an idea for LINQ select query for this XML structure

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm developing a custom search control and setting its configuration based on this sample XML below. So if the user uses my control in his ASPX page and declares a property in his page as:

```
<ccl:Search control id='searchtextbox' PageName='Master' />
```

then I need to consider the **Pagename name='Master'** and set all the properties mentioned under this. Similarly for PageName='SearchResults'

```
<configuration>
 <Pagename name='Master'>
   <Key id='DefaultText'>Search</Key>
   <Key id='SearchBoxCss'>btn</Key>
   <Key id='ButtonText'>Search</Key>
   <Key id='AutocompleteEnabled'>true</Key>
   <Key id='EnableFilterDropNames'>false</Key>
   <Key id='FilterDropNames'>All Areas;Articles</Key>       
 </Pagename>
 <Pagename name='SearchResults'>
   <Key id='DefaultText'>Search</Key>
   <Key id='SearchBoxCss'>btn</Key>
   <Key id='ButtonText'>Search</Key>
   <Key id='AutocompleteEnabled'>false</Key>
   <Key id='EnableFilterDropNames'>false</Key>
   <Key id='FilterDropNames'>All Areas;Articles;Products</Key>                            
 </Pagename>
</configuration>
```

Can you please suggest the necessary **LINQ** code to select based on **Master** or **SearchResults**

What I have tried:

```
var ch = from elem in doc.Descendants("Pagename")
                   where elem.Attribute(XName.Get("name")).Value == "Master"
                   select new
                   {
                       Children = elem.Descendants("Key").Attributes()
                   };
```

this returns me only the list of attributes and not the necessary values.

Comment: you could use XPath for this. Have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Comment: This will be my last option. But currently looking for Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ch = doc.Descendants("PageName")
            .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("name") == "Master")
            .Elements("Key")
            .Select(k => new
                         {
                             Id = (string)k.Attribute("id"),
                             Value = k.Value
                         }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
elem.Descendants("PageName").
            Where(element => element.Attribute("Name").Value == "Master").First().
            Descendants().Select(element => element.Value);
```

meaning-> get the first child with name "Master" and than take the values of all it's children nodes

Comment: This is not gonna work - "Master" is an attribute, not an element.

Comment: @Sayed : saw your response too late, you are right of course, I edited the answer